# Display menu if site is homepage (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

On site I have left menu, which appears on almost every subpage

```
<div class="category_menu">
    <nav class="cat_menu">
        <div class="menu_title parent_cat_name">
            <h6><?php echo $category->name; ?></h6>
        </div>
        <?php rs_left_menu_subcats($subcategories); ?>
    </nav>
</div>
```

I would like do display the another menu if site is homepage. In other cases it should be menu from code I pasted.

What code may I use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can combine [`is_front_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) and [`is_home()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) Wordpress function.

```
<?php if( is_front_page() && is_home() ) { ?>
    // you are on homepage, show your another menu
<?php } else { ?>
<div class="category_menu">
    <nav class="cat_menu">
        <div class="menu_title parent_cat_name">
            <h6><?php echo $category->name; ?></h6>
        </div>
        <?php rs_left_menu_subcats($subcategories); ?>
    </nav>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Looks good, but after use it I don't see no additional menu. I try with only "test" text too and it is also invisible.

Comment: @Pat and in Wordpress administration, which site you using as homepage? Standard WP page with posts, or some static page?

Comment: I use static page.

Comment: Then use only `is_front_page()` in the conditional, so first line of my code must be: `<?php if( is_front_page() ) { ?>`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to display specific content on wordpress homepage than you can do it using [`is_front_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/)

```
if ( is_front_page() ) {    
    // your menu code goes here for home page
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `is_front_page()` and `is_home()` for me doesn't work (WP 5.2.3), I write this condition:

```
global $wp;  
$current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array($_GET), $wp->request));
if ($current_url==get_site_url()) { 
    // code for homepage 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Variant with php -- answer by @hardik solanki

Variant with CSS:

```
.home .category_menu { display: block; }
```